# name of movie where a creature gets trapped inside a building column with a viking-like hero

Tags: story-identification

1 - no animation. real people

2 - probably 80s or early 90s

3 - story is set in the 80s or 90s

4 - Somehow, a creature is trapped inside a pillar of a modern day building, there's a scene where the creature awakens and destroys said pillar.

5 - very gory.

6 - the creature could have been named "fenrir" or "ragnarok"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further reference

*[The Runestone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Runestone)* (1990).

The plot according to Wikipedia:

> Deep in a coal mine in Pennsylvania, a strange stone is found with Norse runes. The stone is transported to NYC, where some archeologists investigate the mystery. Death and destruction follow, as one of the archeologists becomes possessed, and begins killing everyone around him.

Comment: So you're certain that this is the right one? If so, you may want to add a few lines explaining why it matches.

Comment: @SeanDuggan from the cavernous depths of my unconscious mind, the name just popped. Immediately,i proceeded to verify such hypothesis with youtube, after watching 10 to 15 seconds i was certain my quest was over.

Comment: I've been there before. :) So, was there anything that didn't match from what you remembered?

Comment: @SeanDuggan  didn't watch the full movie, just random bits of it. Field work verified that the name of the creature was "fenrir", not ragnarok. I also think that the scene depicted in 4 is actually a composition of various sequences, but i'm pretty sure an innocent concrete pillar or wall gets destroyed.